# Skip client code in JHipster

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

Hi I am using JHipster for creating spring boot java backend. My Requirement is only to create web service. I am creating web-app using commands mentioned in this page https://jhipster.github.io/creating-an-app/

```
yo jhipster
```

I am a bit confused as how to omit client side code completely.
I dont need any index.html or any of js component generated dynamically since I will be just supported apis.

Sorry that this question is bit abstract but this is my doubt.

When I try to run 
`yo jhipster --skip-client` or `yo jhipster:server`

I am not being asked by questions? Is there a bug ?

Answer (score 3):

The command to generate only the backend is:

```
yo jhipster:server
```

I just tried on a JHipster fresh install, and it worked:

> yo jhipster:server
>
> ? (1/10) What is the base name of your application?  (ts)

This could happen if you generate the project with fronted first and when you tried to generate second time you already have the client files.

Comment: Yes as u can see in question both equivalent commands are there but I am note getting question instead it is directly generating everything.

Comment: @sector11 did you generate full app first?; in you log I can see you are "re-generate"; could you try in a empty directory?

Comment: hey friend got it Just found a `.yo-rc.json` in a parent directory.
is the problem. Tried in empty directory current and parent and it worked thanks.